# Suppose a fair coin is flipped and a fair six-sided die is rolled. List the members of the event “the die lands on an even number”.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am still confused on the exact meaning of "members of the event."
So there are three possible numbers that can be landed on that fit this event: 2, 3, and 6. So how would I list these members? I know I cannot just list the numbers by themselves.

Comment: Consider up voting responses and giving [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The sample space would look like (T, 1), (H, 1), (T, 2), ... where (T, 1) is the event that you flip tails and a 1 is rolled on the die.  The members of the event would be the events in the list that have an even roll.

Comment: So basically there would be 6 members of the event total?

Comment: @J.Doe  Yes, the elements of the event are $(H, 2)$, $(H, 4)$, $(H, 6)$, $(T, 2)$, $(T, 4)$, and $(T, 6)$.

Answer (score 0):

An event is a set of outcomes.

The outcomes are the results of flipping a coin and tossing a die.

The members of the event "the die lands on an even number" are all the outcomes where that happens -- all the results of flipping a coin and tossing a die which have the die landing on an even number.